# Remove whitespace to the right of image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am using `Bootstrap` with `React`. I have images that are producing whitespace to the right.

[image: see here]

But I have inspected the elements and can't seem to remove this. I have looked online about `Bootstrap` `Col` but still can't spot the issue. I don't have any CSS related to the Col or img, but I have tried **`padding-right: 0px !important`** and **`margin-right: 0px`**

**HTML:**

```
 <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <div className="form-border">
            <div className="form-box">
              <h1 className="form-title">Compare Cheap Life Insurance</h1>
                <Row className="logo-border">
                  <Col className="logo-col">
                    <img src={aviva} alt="aviva" className="brand-logo" height="75px" width="75px" />
                  </Col>
                  <Col className="logo-col">
                    <img src={aig} alt="aig" className="brand-logo" height="75px" width="75px"/>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
```

Any help would be appreciated. :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/little-field-xtr48?from-embed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing white space bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979392/removing-white-space-bootstrap)

Comment: I found that before and nothing worked. :/

Comment: create a sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/)

Comment: I added the sandbox link in the edit. Can you see the link correctly? First time using it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `pr-0` class to remove white space right of the image. `pr-0`- sets the `padding-right` value to 0

Ref: [bootstrap spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/)

```
<Col className="logo-col pr-0">
<img src={aviva} alt="aviva" className="brand-logo" height="75px" width="75px" />
</Col>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because if you nest your image inside two `col`, then these two cols will divide the parent row by half the width and first col will occupy half of the whole width.
So the best way to remove the right space is to nest that two images inside the same col itself like the following.

```
<Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <div className="form-border">
            <div className="form-box">
              <h1 className="form-title">Compare Cheap Life Insurance</h1>
              <Row className="logo-border">
                <Col className="logo-col">
                  <img
                    src={aviva}
                    alt="aviva"
                    className="brand-logo"
                    height="75px"
                    width="75px"
                  />
                  <img
                    src={aig}
                    alt="aig"
                    className="brand-logo"
                    height="75px"
                    width="75px"
                  />
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
```